# How recursion in scala tree((sealed trait)

Tags: scala

when I programming task in scala I crashed the problem

the error code is missing parameter type for expanded function.

Expected type was: Int
def sum_tree(t : Tree[Int]): int ={

```
sealed trait Tree[Int]
case class Leaf[Int](elem: Int) extends Tree[Int]
case class Node[Int](elem: Int, left: Tree[Int], right: Tree[Int]) extends Tree[Int]
val tree = Node(7, Node(3, Leaf(1), Leaf(2)), Leaf(4))

def sum_tree(t : Tree[Int]): Int = {
  //must use recursion call function.
  case Leaf(elem) => elem
  case Node(elem, l, r) => elem + sum_tree(l) + sum_tree( l )
  case None => 0
}
println("** p6 **")
println(sum_tree(tree)
```

Comment: You're missing a `t match` before the list of `case`s. Also the `case None` can't appear here, `t` is a `Tree[Int]` not an `Option[Tree[Int]]`. And you're calling `sum_tree(l)` twice, you'll probably want one of those to be `sum_tree(r)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html) is missing `match` to be a valid match expression. Also note that `t` is `Tree` and there is `None` declared which implements it so last case clause is invalid; and you were calling `sum_tree(l)` twice when the second one should be `sum_tree(r)`

```scala
def sum_tree(t: Tree[Int]): Int = t match
  case Leaf(elem)       => elem
  case Node(elem, l, r) => elem + sum_tree(l) + sum_tree(r)
```